# Count number only if there is a digit after special character in a df column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

If there's a special character after the number and nothing after the special character, special character is also taken in count.

current output:

```
 109* = 2  

 405,406+,407 = 4

 20++1=3
```

expected output:

```
109* = 1 

405,406+,407 = 3

20++1=2
```

code1:

```
   data['total_books']=data.books.str.count('[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]').add(1)
```

code2:

```
   data.books.str.split(r'[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]').str.len()
```

both the codes yield the same output.

any possible solution.

Comment: change the regex to  `data.books.str.split(r'[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]').str.len() and try.  I changed [\\] to \[\]

Comment: this didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

From the below line

```
data.books.str.split(r'[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]').str.len()
```

I removed the operator **(equal to) =**

```
data.books.str.split(r'[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]').str.len()
```

The result could be equal to expected.

Answer (score -2):

```
str1 = '109*'
str2 = '405,406+,407'
str3 = '20++1'

str_ls = re.split(r'[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}]', str3)
str_ls = [x for x in str_ls if len(x)>0]
)
len(str_ls)
2
```